# Am I missing a pattern?

Tags: naming, design-patterns

I have a class that is a singleton and off of the singleton are properties that hold the instances of all the performance counters in my application.

```
public interface IPerformanceCounters
    {
        IPerformanceCounter AccountServiceCallRate { get; }
        IPerformanceCounter AccountServiceCallDuration { get; }
```

Above is an incomplete snippet of the interface for the class "PerformanceCounters" that is the singleton.

I really don't like the plural part of the name and thought about changing it to "PerformanceCounterCollection" but stopped because it really isn't a collection. I also thought about "PerformanceCounterFactory" but it is really a factory either. After failing with these two names and a couple more that aren't worth mentioning I thought that I might be missing a pattern.

Is there a name that make sense or a change that I could make towards a standardized pattern that would help me put some polish on this object and get rid of the plural name?

I understand that I might be splitting hairs here but that is why I thought that the "Programmers" exchange was the place for this kind of thing. If it is not... I am sorry and I will not make that mistake again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term `IPerformanceCounterSource` could work, referring to a class that is a source of performance counters.

So long as the term is clear, you shouldn't have an issue.  While `~Collection` or `~Set` is gramatically correct, they could be confused for classes that take the form of `ICollection`.

Comment: Given that it is, in some sense, a set then it is probably worth considering if an actual set would be a better implementation

Comment: Though given that in this case performance is probably key probably not.